# zsh's reaction to a program leaking memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, zsh

I am experimenting with memory leaks. When I run the following program from zsh, it starts and is terminated after a while. Is zsh doing it? Who decides when to kill it?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a = 5;

  std::cout << *a << std::endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000000000000; ++i) {
    int *c = (int *) malloc(1024); // 1kb per iteration
    *c = 5;
    std::cout << *c << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you run it, but usually it is the operating system which kills your process after `malloc` returns `NULL` (if unable to allocate new memory) and you attempt to write a value (`5`) to that address. So basically it's a `NULL` pointer dereference where your code attempts to access memory at address `NULL`.

Philosophically speaking, it is the programmer who *decided* to write faulty code and crash his program. :-)

**EDIT:** On the other hand, it might still be the *fault* of the OS (or its programmers) if it attempts to overcommit memory to your process. For example, by default memory overcommit is enabled in Linux. This means that even when the OS has no memory available, it *lies* to the process by letting memory allocation methods to succeed and actually tries to allocate the memory when first accessed by the process. This might lead to cases where `malloc` succeeds and returns a non-`NULL` value, and later when the process attempts to access that memory the OS will try to allocate it. If OS fails, then it either has to block/pause the process or kill it. Linux usually runs its infamous OOM-killer which selects processes to kill when memory allocation fails. And very often the process to kill is the one allocating a lot of memory, your process.